# Draw ECG graph dynamically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI All,

Is there any way to draw a 2d graph of ECG (in wave form) in iphone .I am getting a large anount of data in couple of seconds i mean  the gap will be of just 1 Secs.then is there any way to draw the graph in iphone or any library (IN c or c++) by which i can use it and it draw a live graph of any heart beat analysis and looks alike a live video.

Thanks
Balraj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's Accelerometer example app (available on their iOS developer site, and with full source code) shows how to draw a 2D graph animated several times a second.

Comment: For reference, it is the `AccelerometerGraph` project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Accelerometer sample that hotpaw2 points to, which is reasonably performant when it comes to graphing realtime data, there is the [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) graphing framework.  Core Plot can give you a drop-in component with more options when it comes to formatting your graphs, but it may not be the fastest for displaying many data points that change rapidly on the iPhone.

Comment: YES BRAD I HAVE TRIED THIS THE DATA FOR THE ECG GRAPH IS MUCH MORE LARGE AND FREQUENTLY UPDATED SO WHEN I TRY TO USE THIS MY APP SOMETIME WORKS FINE IN SIMULATOR BUT CRASH IN THE DEVICE ..

IS THERE ANY BETTER APPROACH EXCEPT THIS ONE ...

THANKS ..